# Where to find docs of UWP apps for app-to-app communication?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, documentation, windows-10-universal, microsoft-documentation

Microsoft Universal Windows Platform enables two-way app-to-app communications using the method Luncher.LaunchUriForResultAsync as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-launch-an-app-for-results).

The following Windows apps declare the property ReturnResults in their manifests as "always":

- Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe

The following ones declare it as "optional":

- Microsoft.People_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.WindowsMaps_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.MixedReality.Portal_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.Windows.ParentalControls_cw5n1h2txyewy

This means, these apps are able te respond when called by other ones using the mehtod LaunchUriForResultsAsync.

Where can one find any kind of doc/references of their input/output parameters?

I searched all the microsoft docs websites, google, github, stackoverflow but to no avail!

Answer (score 0):

We suggest use [`LaunchUriAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync) method to launch them with parameter. and  `LaunchUriForResultsAsync` is internal using. Currently, we have no such document for that. If you do want this doc please feel free post your requirement in [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).